# C# Integration Test that calls DLL that calls ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, vs-unit-testing-framework

Want to implement a testing scenario where an Integration Test calls a DLL Method that calls (via REST) a ASP.NET WebAPI app (all on the same solution). When I launch the test (`Ctrl+R,A`), the ASP.NET WebAPI project is not starting and DLL cannot call the respective endpoint.

**The question is**: how can I start the ASP.NET WebAPI project when starting the UnitTest?

I know I can make some other testing scenarios, like UnitTest calling the WebAPI directly, but this is an integration one and would like to test the whole workflow.

**Integration Test project**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task MainWorkflow()
{
   // Target is an object defined on the DLL
   // and instantiated on the unit test [ClassInitialize]
   string fileId = await Target.UploadFiles(theFile);
}
```

**DLL Project**

```
public async Task<String> UploadFiles(string fileToUpload)
{
   var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3000");
   var request = new RestRequest(EndPoints.Upload, Method.PUT);
   // Here a RestSharp code will communicate with localhost
   IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response.Content);
}
```

**ASP.NET WebAPI**

```
public class IntegrationController : ApiController
{
  [HttpPut]
  [Route("api/uploadFile")]
  public async Task<string> UploadFiles()
  {
    HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), folderName, req.Files[0].FileName);
    drawingFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
    // some variables omitted for simplicity...
    return theFileId;
  }
}
```

Comment: First you should start the WebAPI by setting is as startup project and then pressing Ctrl+F5. This will start the Web API project without debugging Mode. Then you press Ctrl R + A to start unit tests.

Comment: that's a good suggestion/workaround @ChetanRanpariya, works, but I cannot debug the ASP.NET WebAPI test.

Comment: Start WebAPI project by pressing F5 to be able to debug it and then Right Click Unit Test and click "Debug" to debug the unit test. Now if the URL of the Web API in DLL is the same as where Web API is running you should be able to hit break point in Web API code when DLL calls web API when you debug Unit Test.

Comment: That doesn't work, tried before. The UnitTest project (on Visual Studio) doesn't accept to be started as it's a DLL. Ideally I was hoping that a .runseeting option to force the ASP.NET to start along with the testing...

Comment: You don't need to start the debugging of entire unit test project. You need to debug selected unit tests.  You can Open `Unit Test Sessions` in visual studio which will list all the unit tests available in your solution there you can select to run or debug one or multiple unit test even when currently visual studio is debuggin web api project.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, unless I'm missing something here, after start the ASP.NET in debug mode, all options to start tests are grayed out (menu, panel, etc)

Comment: Hmm... got it... another way is to open two instances of visual studio for the same solution. One for debugging web api and another for unit tests. This is not a clean way but works for now.